# How to center align <apex:pageBlock> title with CSS?

Tags: visualforce, css, pageblock

I've had a search on google and SE and can't seem to find a definitive answer.

How do I center a pageblock table header? It's nested like this:

```
<div class="pbHeader">
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td class="pbTitle">
                <h2 class="mainTitle">Contact Made - 10%</h2>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

I've tried setting `text-align: center;` on pbHeader and pbTitle, and I've also tried adding `margin: 0 auto;` on them both, I've tried `.pbHeader table tr { text-align:center; }` but every time I've had no luck.

I've resorted to adding 110% of left margin to `.pbTitle` but this isn't the best solution, it only works on my screen.

Can somebody please give me some ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the table generates two columns and if you want to center align the header you have to make it 100% width. Then `text-align: center;` will work as expected. Hope this helps.

```
<style type="text/css">
    .bPageBlock .pbTitle {
        width: 100%;    
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>
```